# objectsDidLoad called after tableview delegate methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform, pfquery

I have a `PFQueryTableViewController` that was working perfectly before I added the `objectsDidLoad` method to my code. I added the method as follows:

```
-(void)objectsDidLoad:(NSError *)error
{
    [super objectsDidLoad:error];


    for(PFObject *object in self.objects)
    {
        PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"SchoolDebate"];
    [query whereKey:@"SchoolHappening" equalTo:object];
    PFObject *debateObject = [query getFirstObject];
        NSString *votesString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"+%@ -%@", [debateObject objectForKey:@"proVotes"], [debateObject objectForKey:@"conVotes"]];
        [self.voteStrings addObject:votesString];
    }

}
```

However, when I run my app now it crashes after a second of the "Loading..." white page. The breakpoint is on a line that accesses the `self.voteStrings`array in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. I think this error happens because the tableview delegate methods are being called before `objectsDidLoad`, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: What is the error/exception reported? Best guess is an attempt to retrieve an array element that does not exist (i.e., the index is out of the bounds of the array).

Comment: The error is that the array self.voteStrings is empty

Comment: You likely need to change `numberOfRowsInSection` method so that it returns the number of array elements. Show the code for `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: The number of objects is not changing, but I have explicitly returned [self.objects count]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by putting my code in objectsDidLoad, then calling `super` at the end of the method (before refreshing my table).